# Performance impact of PowerMockito

Tags: spring, junit, powermock

We had the following pattern and it had dramatic impact on test-execution time.

I want to understand why.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeSingleton.class)
public class SomeTest {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeSingleton.class);
    Mockito.when(SomeSingleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(new SomeSingleton());
}
```

The class SomeSingleton is very legacy and (no joke) gets its shared instance from the spring container.

Remark: I added a public static setter for the instance (spoiling the very idea of the singleton) but won 25 seconds for this!

**Question: What exactly does "PrepareForTest" and "mockStatic" do that takes 25secs ?**

Comment: I think the best way check what caused this is to use a debugger (and the use "Step over").

Comment: step over the PrepareForTest? Step over the reflection calls inside Powermockito? From that I wont learn anything i guess.

Comment: I mean step over within mockStatic. -- I hope that you will find the invokation that takes 25sec. After you get the method, repeat the whole stuff but within this method. And so drill down until you find your problem.